# Decimals on x axis in data breaks chart.js scatter

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart made with chart.js, it works perfectly except when I pass data with decimals on x, for example:
0:
{x: 9.8, y: 746.0236183946838}
1:
{x: 10.8, y: 787.3400989688439}
2:
{x: 11.8, y: 826.9850534238384}

the same example but with, 10, 11 and 12, works fine, so I dont know where the problem may be as I assumed it should work as long as the data is passed, this is the code I have:

```
          var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
          
          var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'scatter',
            data: {
              datasets: [{
                label: 'Points',
                borderColor: window.chartColors.purple,
                borderWidth: 2,
                fill: false,
                data: storage,
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.purple,
              }
            ]
            },
        
              title: {
                display: false,
                text: 'Despressuration Chart',
                fontSize: 18
              },
              events: ['click'],
              tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: true
              },
              hover: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: true
              },
              elements: {
                line: {
                    tension: 0 // disables bezier curves
                }
              },            
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Flow (Ft3/Min)'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            suggestedMin: 0,    // minimum will be 0, unless there is a lower value.
                            suggestedMax: yPoints[length] + 80,
                            beginAtZero: true   // minimum value will be 0.
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Induced Pressure (Pa)'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            suggestedMin: 0,    // minimum will be 0, unless there is a lower value.
                            suggestedMax: xPoints[xLength] + 10,//Math.round(xPoints[xLength]) + 10,
                            beginAtZero: true   // minimum value will be 0.
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
          });   
        }
```

storage comes from an array I calculated previously, and it works fine, the problem here its only with showing the data, but the data itself is correct

I have tried giving it stepSize: 5, precision: 0,but neither of those worked, I also dont want to round the numbers from storage. Thanks in advice.